# Create list by subtracting the nth+1 value from the nth values of another list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I need to create a list which returns the difference between the nth and nth + 1 values of another list. Is there any way of simplifying the code below to work for any size lists?

```
mylist = [1,5,15,30,60]

w = mylist[1] - mylist[0]
x = mylist[2] - mylist[1]
y = mylist[3] - mylist[2]
z = mylist[4] - mylist[3]

difflist = [w,x,y,z]

print difflist
```

And this will return `[4,10,15,30]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and `list comprehension`:

```
>>> [ a-b for a,b in zip(mylist[1:], mylist[:-1]) ]
=> [4, 10, 15, 30]
```

#driver values

```
IN : mylist = [1,5,15,30,60]
```

---

In case, you want the good old fashioned traversing through the list using its `index`:

```
>>> [ mylist[i+1]-mylist[i] for i in range(len(mylist)-1) ]
=> [4, 10, 15, 30]
```

---

Although, using `zip` is better than traversing through its `index` as you don't need to generate the list for `range` as in case of `python2` and is more **Pythonic**.

**EDIT :**  the `zip` method can also be just `zip(mylist[1:], mylist[:])`

Comment: You don't need to perform the second slice; `zip()` will stop at the end of the shortest sequence.

Comment: Just a precaution of sorts. :D Makes me feel safer. But point noted.

Comment: Sure @ChuckM, glad to help.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at this one:

```
mylist = [1,5,15,30,60]

def diff(myList):
    return [myList[i+1] - myList[i] for i in range(len(myList)-1)]

l = diff(mylist)
print(l)
```

The output is:

```
[4, 10, 15, 30]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>>[j-i for i, j in zip(mylist[:-1], mylist[1:])]
=> [4, 10, 15, 30]
```

Or if you might want to consider numpy. Using numpy, the answer is:

```
>>>import numpy
>>>numpy.diff(mylist)
=>array([ 4, 10, 15, 30])
```

or

```
>>>list(numpy.diff(mylist))
=>[4,10,15,30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it.

```
mylist = [1,5,15,30,60]


def diff(mylist):
    return [x - mylist[i - 1] for i, x in enumerate(mylist)][1:]


print(diff(mylist))
# [4, 10, 15, 30]
```

You have to also define what you want to do when there is one element in the list. In all the existing answers, including this one, you will get an empty list as a result if there is only one element in the input list. For example, when `mylist = [1]`, then the output is a just empty list `[]`.